# Python. Splitting a list

Tags: python, string, list

This code counts how many times a word appears in a sentence:
But my question is about the marked line: `for word in words.split():`

When I run this code it runs. But when I write my own code Python throws an error with the following message: `“list” have  no attribute split()`.

I don’t understand that and found no answer. I just started learning Python, many things are unclear to me. Thank you for your help.

```
words , pattern = input().lower().split(',')

dico = {}

for word in words.split():

    dico[word.strip()] = dico.get(word.strip(), 0) + 1

print("Word '{}' appear {} time(s)".format(pattern.strip(), dico.get(pattern.strip(), 0)))
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "when I write my own code". What input are you giving the program?

Comment: If you ask a question, please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This includes input, expected and real output and a full traceback of the error message.

Comment: Sorry i Forget that . My on code that means I wrote the same function and by the line: for word in words:, I get an error and the original code that I put here doesn’t .fro

Comment: Sorry i Forget that . My on code that means I wrote the same function and by the line: for word in words:, I get an error and the original code that I put here doesn’t . For example input was: ‘this is an example’ and the pattern to count: ‘is’. I don’t understand why that is splitted the times.

Comment: Sorry when I will be on my computer I put here my code. I’m on the tablet I can’t click Enter :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your algorithm can be written without a dictionary, utilising `list.count`. Below is an example.

```
words, pattern = input().lower().split(',')

words = [i.strip() for i in words.split()]
pattern = pattern.strip()

print("Word '{}' appear {} time(s)".format(pattern, words.count(pattern)))

# hello then now then, then
# Word 'then' appear 2 time(s)
```

Comment: I guess without a dictionary it’s quicker. Thank you!

Comment: Np, feel free to accept (green tick on left) if this resolves your issue.

Comment: In your code occurs no issue too in the expression: for i in words.split().    But when write simple: for x in words.split():
 print(x). I got an error wrote above .  Don’t understand python